# Flip SQL Result

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

How to do this in sql ?

I have select and the result are :

```
1 a
2 b
3 c
4 d
5 e
```

then I want the result to display like

```
1 2 3 4 5
a b c d e
```

Thanks Guys!

Comment: Provide table structure and your select query.

Comment: This is generally referred to as a `PIVOT`. There are plenty of examples both on here of questions and also in the MSDN documentation. Exact details may vary if e.g. there aren't a fixed number of result columns

Answer (score 3):

You can use pivot

```
select [1],[2],[3],[4],[5]
from
(
  select column1, column2
  from mytable
) d
pivot
(
  max(column2)
  for column1 in ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5])
) piv;
```

**[SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/38c4a/7)**

Comment: Column names shouldn't be in [brackets]?

Comment: @StanislovasKalašnikovas:- I rarerly think that someone will make the column names as 1,2,3.. Anyways updated my code. Although the point was to use PIVOT and the logic.

Answer (score 1):

You can use PIVOT:

```
-- Create sample data

CREATE TABLE Test
(
  A INT,
  B NVARCHAR(10)
)
INSERT INTO Test (A, B) VALUES (1, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (3, 'c'), (4, 'd'), (5, 'e')

-- Pivot query

SELECT [1],[2],[3],[4],[5]
FROM
(
  SELECT A, B
  FROM Test
) x
PIVOT
(
  MIN(B)
  FOR A IN ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5])
) piv;
```

OUTPUT:

```
1   2   3   4   5
a   b   c   d   e
```

**[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6e2d06/11)**

As you asked, dynamic pivot should be like that:

```
SELECT @cols += ([Name]) + ','
FROM   (
        SELECT  Name
        FROM    Table
        ) a
SET @cols   = LEFT(@cols, LEN(@cols) - 1)
SET @sql    = 
'SELECT * 
 FROM 
    (
    SELECT Col1 as [NamePiv], 
           Col2 as [Val]
    FROM   Table1
    ) x
    PIVOT
    (
        MIN (Val)
        FOR NamePiv IN (' + @cols +') 
    ) p'
```

Comment: Hi Stanislovavs, thanks for this sample query but what if the column name if dynamic ?  the column name are dynamically selected on database table.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need to use pivot statement, https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx

```
-- Potentially your case example:
DECLARE @t TABLE (id int, val CHAR(1));
INSERT INTO @t VALUES (1, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (3, 'c'), (4, 'd'), (5, 'e')
-- Pivot table with one row and five columns
SELECT 'Value' AS 'Id', 
        [1], [2], [3], [4], [5]
FROM @t AS SourceTable
PIVOT
(
max(val)
FOR id IN ([1], [2], [3], [4], [5])
) AS PivotTable;
```